# Selecting multiple options in multiple select box with "[]" in its name, with ajax

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to dynamically select options in a multiple select box, from the data received from ajax.

HTML

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="sbox[]" name="sbox[]">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$.post(
    "test.php",
    {
       action: "test"
    },
    function(data) {
       //data received is in the format of "2,3"
       splitText = data.split(",");
       $.each(splitText, function(k,v) {
           $("#sbox[]").children("option[value="+v+"]").attr("selected","selected");
       });
    }
);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: write `+v+` instead of `+value+`

Comment: Already said it two times, it was a typo and i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because jQuery thinks `#sbox[]` is the ID selector `#sbox` with an empty attribute selector `[]`, which isn't valid.

You could escape the square brackets so your selector becomes `#sbox\[\]`. But the square brackets aren't needed in your ID in the first place; just call it `id="sbox"` and select `#sbox`. The square brackets are only necessary in the `name` attribute to designate your select as an array of values.

Comment: Well, normally it is not needed, but the form is submitted by serializing the fields, so to grab it as a array, i need to use the brackets.

Comment: @mrN: That's for the `name` attribute, not `id`.

Comment: @BoltClock, is it ok, if I dont use the brackets in id then.

Comment: @mrN: Isn't that what I said? Read my answer again, I edited it a little to elaborate things.

Comment: @BoltClock, No, I was just not thinking that id would be the one causing it. But Thanks, it worked. Would you mind updating your answer? I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$.post(
    url: "test.php",
    function(data) {
       //data received is in the format of "2,3"
       splitText = data.split(",");
       $.each(splitText, function(k,v) {
           $("#sbox\[\]").children("option[value="+v+"]").attr("selected","selected");
       });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `value` in the each-loop instead of `v` like the parameter is named in the declaration

```
   $.each(splitText, function(k,v) {
       $("#sbox[]").children("option[value="+v+"]").attr("selected","selected");
   });
```

Comment: Oh... Oops, that was a typo so

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact code you use, than value in $.each is undefined. You are using v identifier in function. should be like

```
$("#sbox[]").children("option[value="+v+"]").attr("selected","selected");
```

And you SHOULD change the id. As from w3, [ ]  signs are not allowed

> Specifies a unique id for an element. Naming rules:
>
> Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
>   Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z),
>   digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
>   periods (".") Values are
>   case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

It would just be easier if you changed the id.

If you absolutely must do it, you have to escape the brackets as they are used in selector syntax

```
change $("#sbox[]")

to $("#sbox\[\]")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible issues here, try this out:

```
$.post(
"test.php",
{
   action: "test"
},
function(data) {
   //data received is in the format of "2,3"
   var splitText = data.split(",");
   var select = $('[id="sbox[]"]').get(0);
   $.each(splitText, function(k,v) {
       $.each(select.options, function(i, option) {
           if(option.value == v)
               option.selected = true;
           else
               option.selected = false;
       });
   });
}
);
```

The first thing is that `#id` selector works well when `id` is alpha-numeric (`-` and `_` are also allowed). So to use the `[]` substring in id you'd want to locate it using attribute selector. Alternatively if it is the only id starting with `sbox` you may try this: `$('[id^=sbox]')`.

Another item to fix potentially is setting the `selected` attribute on `<option>`. I'm not sure if it works as you expected, but addressing the `Option` DOM object as shown above should work fine.

An the last one is the minor correction - you're locating the `<select>` element each cycle iteration, likely you'd want to do that once before cycle starts.

Hope this helps.